# Does a Silverlight 4 trusted app have access to the comm port?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I know that Silverlight 4 has "Hardware device access".  Does anyone know if I can read from the com port in a Silverlight 4 trusted app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the following features

1. Trusted network access
2. Access to the filesystem
3. Create and use COM objects (not the com port)
4. Full keyboard access in full screen mode

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/11/18/whats-new-in-silverlight-4-complete-guide-new-features.aspx

Since the com port acts like a file (via COM1, COM2), perhaps you could read and write to that using your filesystem access.

All of this is out-of-the-browser only